# Inserting data into a temp table from an open query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've looked online and you can not drop variables into an open query so easily so I modified my query and it says the #TempOT temp table is "Invalid object name '#TempOT'."  What am I doing wrong that is causing the temp table not to get populated?

```
    BEGIN
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempOT') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #TempOT
END;

 DECLARE @TSQL As varchar(1024)
 DECLARE @AS400Query As varchar(1024)
 SET @AS400Query = 'SELECT * from blah.blahlibrary.AS400Table where DATETS  BETWEEN '+ @BegofMonthForAS400 + ' AND ' + @DateForAS400 
 SET @TSQL = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(ISERIES,' + '''' + @AS400Query +'''' + ')'

INSERT INTO #TempOT
 EXEC(@TSQL)
END
```

i have also tried this and it does not work

```
    BEGIN
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempOT') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #TempOT
END;

 DECLARE @TSQL As varchar(1024)
 DECLARE @AS400Query As varchar(1024)
 SET @AS400Query = 'SELECT * from valdosta.PRDATA.PRTIMELM where DATETS BETWEEN '+ @BegofMonthForAS400 + ' AND ' + @DateForAS400 
 SET @TSQL = ' INSERT INTO #TempOT SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(ISERIES,' + '''' + @AS400Query +'''' + ')'


EXEC(@TSQL)

END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You DROP the TEMP table and then you are trying to INSERT data into it.
You need to create the TEMP table within your script first.

Comment: i drop the temp table if there is an existing temp table with that object ID  then when i insert it is supposed to automatically create the table with the column names and data types mirroring the source table. but that is not happening. if i comment the drop table  statement i get the same error. everywhere i look is saying that it supposed to be this way. im a bit confused as to why its failing honestly

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in fact, that you are creating temporary table within `EXEC` statement. Created table `#TempOT` is dropped immediately after batch is executed` and is not visible for your main query. There are at least two possibilities (if you want to use temp tables):

1. Instead of creating local temporary table, create global temporary table with `##` before table name (difference between them is explained [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186986.aspx#Anchor_1)). In my opinion, you should drop this table at the end of your main query.
2. Create `#TempOt` with all columns before `EXEC` statement where you will be able without problem to populate table `#TempOt` with desired data.